# How can stay on the last item which is off the screen on the listbox

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am using a listbox on my MainPage.xaml. I can see the content goes off and on the Windows Phone Emulator screen by using the mouse move up and down. After I release the mouse, the content will start from the first item. Let's say I want to select the last item on the listbox. How can I keep the last item on the screen? Hope you can help me or give me an example or an idea to solve this problem. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

There is my user Control:

```
<UserControl x:Class="CMSPhoneApp.QueueListControl"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
d:DesignHeight="480" d:DesignWidth="480"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CMSPhoneApp"  >

<UserControl.Resources>       
    <local:VisibilityConverter x:Key="VisibilityConverter"/>
    <local:ColumSpanConverter x:Key="ColumSpanConverter"/>        
</UserControl.Resources>


<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot"  Background="Transparent">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">       
            <ListBox x:Name="lst" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,6,0,0"   VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="400"    
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyQueue}"  
                      SelectedItem="{Binding Path=CurrentQueue, Mode=TwoWay}"  >
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Border BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" BorderBrush="Blue">
                            <Grid Width="auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" >                                  
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>                                          
                                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="35" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="250"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="125" />
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <Image Source="{Binding Type}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"/>
                                    <TextBlock  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"  Grid.ColumnSpan= "{Binding isSpan, Converter={StaticResource ColumSpanConverter}}" Text="{Binding summary}" TextWrapping="Wrap"
                                             Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextAccentStyle}"  />
                                    <Button x:Name="btnAction" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" ClickMode="Press" Click="btnAction_Click" Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle1}"
                                            Visibility="{Binding isVisibility, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConverter}}"
                                         Tag="{Binding callNumber}">

                                        <Button.Content>
                                            <TextBlock Width="85" Height="70" Text="{Binding ActionCaption}" 
                                                       Style="{StaticResource LabelStyle_20}"     />
                                        </Button.Content>
                                    </Button>

                                </Grid>
                                </Border>
                    </DataTemplate>                    

                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>

    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

The xaml page use the above user control.

```
   <phone:PhoneApplicationPage xmlns:my="clr-namespace:CMSPhoneApp"  
x:Class="CMSPhoneApp.TestPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignHeight="768" d:DesignWidth="480"
shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CMSPhoneApp"
  xmlns:toolkit="clr- namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"
  >

<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>

    <local:QueueItemViewModel x:Key="TestViewModel"/>
    <DataTemplate x:Name="PickerItemTemplate">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding city}" FontSize="24" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Name="PickerFullModeItemTemplate">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding city}" Margin="16 0 0 0" FontSize="24" FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyLight}" />                        
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>


</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
<!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent" DataContext="{StaticResource TestViewModel}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>           
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
    <StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel" Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28"  >
        <TextBlock x:Name="ApplicationTitle" Text="MY APPLICATION" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="PageTitle" Text="Test page" Margin="9,-7,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
    </StackPanel>

    <StackPanel x:Name="City" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0"  Orientation="Horizontal">
        <toolkit:ListPicker   x:Name="listPicker" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource PickerItemTemplate}"  
              Header="Location"   CacheMode="BitmapCache" Width="194" 
                        SelectedItem="{Binding city}"        />

    </StackPanel>
    <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->       
        <my:QueueListControl x:Name="lst" Grid.Row="2"/>     
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="3" Orientation="Horizontal" >
        <Button x:Name="btnQueue" Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle1}" Content="Queue"/>
        <Button x:Name="btnRefresh" Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle1}" Content="Refresh"/>
        </StackPanel>

</Grid>
```

The code behind for set the itemSource after getting the GetResponseStream:

```
 Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => lst.lst.ItemsSource = ar.cmsQueue));
```

Comment: You might want to add some of your code here. You might be rebinding your control (if I understand your problem correctly). Could you post up some of your XAML and related C#/VB?

Comment: put some sample code and screens so that we could analyze your problem more correctly

Comment: Are you fixing the height of the Listbox? make sure it is not more than the height of the screen

Comment: @Layoric,  I posted my code as Answer because it is too long.

Comment: @nkchandra, I didn't set the Listbox height. It is put it on the grid row, and the grid row height is auto.

Comment: @MilanAggarwal, please read the answer 2 because I cannot add my code on the comment. I posted it as answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There you are. You are not setting the Height of the Listbox and so it is getting its height from its parent which is Auto(which means there is no boundary for height of ListBox). So by holding mouse you are able to scroll to any item, but cannot stop at a particular item. Fix the Height to ListBox somewhere around 400 and then check. Hopefully that should solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing anything similar to this anywhere on your code?

`listbox.ScrollIntoView(0);`, where listbox is the name of your ListBox on your mainPage.xaml

Try to prevent using such line of code. Apart from this, I cant understand the nature of your problem without some code. Hope it helps